# Can't click an element from a Bootstrap Dropdown in Selenium WebDriver using Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, dropdown

Requirement: I need to download container information from:

https://elines.coscoshipping.com/ebusiness/cargoTracking

Problem: When the page loads, by default the dropdown shows Bill of Lading, but since I need this search to be by Container, when I try to select Container it still stays as Bill of Lading.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="ivu-select-selection" style="background-color: rgb(247, 247, 
 249);">
   <span class="ivu-select-placeholder" style="display: none;">
   Select</span> 
   <span class="ivu-select-selected-value">Bill Of Lading</span> 
   <!----> 
   <i class="ivu-icon ivu-icon-chevron-up ivu-select-chevron-down" 
   style="display: none;"></i> 
   <i class="ivu-icon ivu-icon-chevron-down ivu-select-arrow"></i>
</div>

<ul class="ivu-select-dropdown-list">
  <div data-v-213ece08="">
    <li class="ivu-select-item ivu-select-item-selected">
        Bill Of Lading
      </li>
    <li class="ivu-select-item" style="">
        Booking
      </li>
    <li class="ivu-select-item" style="">
      Container
      </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

And this is my code:

```
SHPG=['COSCO']
Lst=[]

for i in SHPG:

    #Dictionary so separate containers by shipper
    containers=df1[pd.DataFrame(df1.values.tolist()).eq(i).any(axis=1)]
    #Lst=containers['Container'].tolist()
    Lst=['CBHU4377843','CSNU1803584']

    if i == 'COSCO':
     #ONE
     driver.get('https://elines.coscoshipping.com/ebusiness/cargoTracking')
    
        element= WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        expect.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ivu-btn 
        ivu-btn-primary ivu-btn-large']")))
    
        #Clicking buttons
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='ivu-btn ivu-btn- 
        primary ivu-btn-large']").click()

        time.sleep(2)
    
        for j in Lst:
        
            #identify dropdown with Select class
        
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.ivu-select- 
            selection").click()
       
        
            options= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.ivu-select- 
            dropdown-list")
        
                for opt in options:
                    if print(opt.text)=='Container':
                      opt.click()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that in two steps after directing to correct site

```js
#Click dropdown selected value to show list
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='cargoTrackTpye']//span[contains(@class,'selected')]").click()

#Click list option Container
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[normalize-space()='Container']").click()
```

If you encounter exception ElementClickInterceptedException , then use javascript "click" instead

```js
#Click dropdown selected value to show list
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='cargoTrackTpye']//span[contains(@class,'selected')]"))

#Click list option Container
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[normalize-space()='Container']"))
```

Comment: Hi Millie, thank you very much for the help, this worked perfectly!!